using cli-testing-library to run/test a non-Node command
Regarding cli-testing-library, I'm trying many things to test my CLI tool but can't run it.
const { code, stdout, stderr } = await execute("sh", "./fdup . package*");
const { code, stdout, stderr } = await execute("sh -c", "./fdup . package*");


What am I doing wrong? Thanks!
(The docs could have an example of a non-Node command.)
  Error: spawn sh -c ENOENT
      at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
      at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'spawn sh -c',
    path: 'sh -c',
    spawnargs: [ '/Users/lsoares/so-1/fdup', '.', 'package*' ]
  }

